# Insert content inside form using Jquery .ready() and .append()

Tags: jquery

I need some help. I am trying to insert an html tag inside a form using Jquery .append() inside $(document).ready().

This is what i have tested and not working:

```
Jquery part:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inner").append('<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxall">');
});

HTML part:
<form class="inner" action="" method="post">
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

LE: i have analyzed the code in firebug and i notice that the form looks something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEVuA.png. What is the color of the form shaded?

LE: take care of the html validation part, very important, for me didn't work because the html code was invalid in the document where i implemented this POC. (See picture above)

Comment: Your example works for me in Firefox and JQuery 1.8.2. Maybe specify the browser and Jquery versions? And by works for me, I mean, that the checkbox appears in the form on page load.

Comment: try closing the `<input>` tag?

Comment: i'd check for javascript errors earlier in the document.ready code. this works fine on its own.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran I have no errors at least this is what firebug console is saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing something wrong.

I have just copy / paste your code and it is working : http://jsfiddle.net/gA9ry/

```
Jquery part:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inner").append('<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxall">');
});

HTML part:
<form class="inner" action="" method="post">
</form>
```

Comment: I have fallowed your link and i see nothing in result window. Used control+return and still no result. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Removed all my profile settings and let the default one for firefox. It is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inner").append('<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxall" />');
});
```

Also check that all your jQuery is loaded etc.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works. Look in your ErrorConsole. I am sure jQuery is not correctly loaded, and a error like '$' is not defined will occur.

Answer (score 0):

My page top to bottom works:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inner").append('<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxall">');
});
</script>

<form class="inner" action="" method="post">
</form>
```